# blinking on rotation in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation

here is my code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>
#include <math.h>
#define pi 3.14;
float angle=3;
void reshape(int w, int h)
{
if(h==0) h=1;
glViewport(0,0,w,h);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0,w,0,h,-1,1);

}
void display(void)
{
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   
    glRotatef(angle++,0,1.0,1.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(10,10);
    glVertex2f(30,20);
    glVertex2f(30,30);
    glVertex2f(10,30);
    glEnd();
    glRotatef(angle++,0,1.0,1.0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
        glVertex2f(300,300);
        int segments=20;
        GLfloat angle=0;
        for(int i=0;i<=segments; i++)
        {
            angle=i*2*pi; angle=angle / (segments);
            glVertex2f(300+cos(angle)*30,300+sin(angle)*30);

        }
        glEnd();        

    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc , argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH|GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutCreateWindow("first");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return(0);
}
```

here the problems are

1. cannot see the rotation correctly just blinking the rectangle. Don't know is it rotating      or not.

2.the circle is not rotating even there is code for rotation. why?

3.what change I made if I want only rectangle or circle is rotated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `1.` cannot see the rotation correctly just blinking the rectangle.

You're probably running waaaaay too fast.  Use a timer callback to issue `glutPostRedisplay()`s every 16ms or so.

> `2.` the circle is not rotating even there is code for rotation. why?

```
glRotatef(angle++,0,1.0,1.0);
                    ^^^
```

You're rotating outside the X/Y plane and exceeding the depth limits of your `glOrtho()` call resulting in clipped fragment.  Bump your `nearVal`/`farVal` to accommodate:

```
glOrtho(0,w,0,h,-1000,1000);
```

> `3.` what change I made if I want only rectangle or circle is rotated?

Remove one of the `glRotatef()`s.

---

All together:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const double pi = 3.14159;

float angle=3;
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    glOrtho(-w,w,-h,h,-1000,1000);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);

    //glRotatef(angle++,0,1.0,1.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(10,10);
    glVertex2f(30,20);
    glVertex2f(30,30);
    glVertex2f(10,30);
    glEnd();

    glRotatef(angle++,0,1.0,1.0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    glVertex2f(300,300);
    const int segments=20;
    for(int i=0;i<=segments; i++)
    {
        const GLfloat angle = ( i*2*pi ) / (float)segments;
        glVertex2f(300+cos(angle)*30,300+sin(angle)*30);
    }
    glEnd();        

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void timer( int value )
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc( 16, timer, 0 );
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc , argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH|GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutCreateWindow("first");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutTimerFunc( 0, timer, 0 );
    glutMainLoop();
    return(0);
}
```